# Was away from site for a while bounty expired

Tags: support

I asked a question a while ago, the bounty on it expired and I sort of forgot about it. I now see that one answer has been awarded a bounty of +25 which I think I did not award. Anyhow, is there anyway to award a bounty now to an answer that was particularly helpful?

Answer (score 3):

In your absence, half the bounty automatically went to the highest-voted answer.  You lost all 50 rep points that you put up for the bounty, though; this always happens regardless.

You can't award the bounty now; you'd have to put a second bounty on it (and you can only award bounties to new answers -- i.e., answers that show up after you post the bounty).  So you should probably just upvote and accept the answer you found helpful.

Comment: Great answer, Matthew Read.  I, Maika Sakuranomiya, do not do any bounties at all on Stack Exchange, as they cost too much reputation.  You prove it is a good choice not to.

Comment: 50 rep is not much, but obviously it's up to you how you value your internet points.  I proved nothing except that it's not a good choice to forget about things if you want to do something with them.

Comment: Good point about the points being nonrecoverable regardless; they're sunk costs once offered. The full bounty, when manually awarded, would have been all 50 points, so I guess 25 points just sort of disappeared from the reputation economy. Then again, SE isn't a zero-sum system, and the total rep increases hundreds of times faster than it decreases, so I'm not worried :P

Comment: @user45266 Yes, good to call out that it's not a zero-sum system!